# How to treat batch of inputs in keras?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN trained on input of shape `(None,128,128,1)` (grayscale images). I want to use this model weights as basis in another model to extract features (without training the first model) which accepts two inputs of shape `[(None,128,128,10), (None,10,8)]` here `10` is the number of images in single sample.
Basically it accepts `10` images of shape `(128,128)`.  I considered each image as channel since Conv layer in keras accepts 4D input.

My model would look something like this

```
def create_model():

    trajectory_input = Input(shape=(10, 8), name='trajectory_input')
    image_input  = Input(shape=(128, 128, 10), name='image_input')
    
    x_aware = (Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), weights=model1_weights, activation='relu'))(image_input)

    x = concatenate([trajectory_input , x_aware])
    x_reg = (Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[trajectory_input, image_input], outputs=[x_reg])
```

Is there any way in keras to treat this single sample as a batch of images instead of one single sample while extracting features from model1 (here `x_aware` layer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a `[None, 126, 126, 32, 10]` sized tensor at the end, you'll need to define a custom layer for this.

```
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, conv_layer):
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
    self.conv_layer = conv_layer

  def build(self, input_shape):
    pass
  
  def call(self, x):
    return tf.stack([self.conv_layer(tf.expand_dims(t, axis=-1)) for t in tf.unstack(x, axis=-1)], axis=-1)
```

and call it as,

```
x_aware = CustomLayer(conv_layer)(image_input)
```